# Hide HTML element so it does not take up any space

Tags: html, forms, input

Can someone explain how I can modify the second input id shown below so that it is not visible on the page and also does not take up any space on the page?

```
    <section>
    <label for="muni">Municipality</label>
    <div>
    <input id="county_select" type="text" />
    <input id="county_no" type="text" value="" disabled="disabled" style="visibility:hidden" />
    </div>
    </section>
```

Currently, this second input id takes up space on my form and I don't want it to take up any space.  Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

Use `display: none;`, as shown:

```
<input id="county_no" type="text" value="" disabled="disabled" style="display: none;" />
```

Reference:

- [The CSS `display` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/display).

Answer (score 3):

```
display:none in stead of visibility:hidden
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `style="display:none;"` instead of `visibility:hidden`

`visibility:hidden` leaves space.

Answer (score 1):

You can style the input using CSS, targeting it via its `id` tag.

In your `.css` file:

`#county_no {
    display: none;
}`

Styling HTML inline should be avoided.